# Website not working in Tor

Tags: website

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-view-ntuserdat
is not working in Tor.
Any website of techwalla.com is not working in Tor.
[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Send an email to TechWalla and ask them why they don't like that you access their webpages through Tor. Share the answer here later, please.

Answer (score 2):

The website is blocking connections from Tor exit relays. There's not much you can do to get around it while using Tor. You can try using new circuits until you get a circuit with an exit relay that the website hasn't blocked yet. You can do this by clicking the lock icon in the URL bar and then clicking the "New Circuit" button. If that doesn't work, then you'll likely have to use a VPN instead.